# Where can I find or download Perl's p2hp utility?

Tags: perl

I have `perl` installed, but many commands (`perl` utilities) are not available. I thing they should be come along with `perl` after `perl` is installed. But there are simply no such commands. And I googled to find where I can download them, but looks like nowhere tells me where to get them.

```
 root@opensolaris:~# which find2perl

 which: no find2perl in (/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin)

 root@opensolaris:~# which h2ph

 which: no h2ph in (/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin)

 root@opensolaris:~# perl -v

 This is perl, v5.8.4 built for i86pc-solaris-64int
 (with 31 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

 Copyright 1987-2004, Larry Wall
```

Comment: try looking in the directory returned by [which perl]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be over at /usr/perl5/5.8.4/bin/h2ph .

Comment: Yes, it is there, thanks.
root@opensolaris:/usr/perl5/5.8.4/bin# ls -l h2ph
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin 24723 2008-11-20 08:30 h2ph

Comment: But looks like there is no syscall.h, I am trying to use perl to call syscall
oracle@opensolaris:/usr/include$ find ./|grep syscall
oracle@opensolaris:/usr/include$

Answer (score 0):

> This is perl, v5.10.0 built for i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi

And i have these perl base modules installed.

- perl
- perl-base
- perl-debug
- perl-modules

And it works for me. I even uninstalled perl-debug and it still works. (ubuntu 9.04)

Answer (score 0):

h2ph isn't provided in your Solaris and they tend not to provide the 'extras' or 'utilities' for perl, like 'rename' and 'find2perl' for example.

find /mount/point/here -name 'h2ph" -ls

Its definately not like linux and the layout is odd as well.